# JvectorMap add color to small countries

Tags: javascript, jvectormap

I know that in JvectorMap some small countries are missing.

But I need a way to assign a color also to small countries, because I need to loop over a list of state and get the color.

```
myMap.series.regions[0].elements[state].element.properties.fill
```

Because small countries are not present, the script give errors when it checks Singapore for example.

How could fix this?